# How sign app new user in multipanels on laravel 10/filament 3 site?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

Working with multipanels on laravel 10/filament 3 site I created a new panel with command

```
php artisan make:filament-panel app
```

and under this panels managers would work, meanwhile default "admin" would be for adminers only

I made modification in app/Providers/Filament/AdminPanelProvider.php :

```
class AdminPanelProvider extends PanelProvider
{
    public function panel(Panel $panel): Panel
    {
        return $panel
//            ->default() I hide these methods
//            ->login()
            ->id('admin')
            ->path('admin')
```

and in app/Providers/Filament/AppPanelProvider.php :

```
return $panel
    ->default() // I added these options
    ->registration()
    ->login()
    ->id('app')
    ->path('app')
```

But when I opened Sign up form in "/app/register" url and filling try to save new user I got error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'branch_id' doesn't have a default value
```

branch_id - is field for Multi-Tenancy in users table.
a) I did not find method for submitting of Sign App form
b) to leave users.branch_id empty ? Not sure is it good solution ?
c) To apply some default branch_id?
d) I would prefer to run signup from "/app/" with current branch selected to create a new user under current branch, but how to call Sign Up for in this case ?

Which decision could be good here and how to make it ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.28.0",
"filament/filament": "^3.0-stable",
"spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.11.0",
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you get or intent to get your current selected branche? If you want to select it during register you should implement your own register page in filament. If you can deside it somehow, you should just implement in in your observer or static::creating, so that it gets automatically set by Laravel